# Translate blocks in page_manager variant

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

I am building a multilingual Drupal site.  My 'static' pages are built using the [page_manager](https://www.drupal.org/project/page_manager) module.  I am using the core multilingual modules and the [Translation Manager Tool](https://www.drupal.org/project/tmgmt).  With these I can translate my custom entities / block / blog posts and the like.

The problem I am having is that I cannot translate the content of the blocks I have placed in my page_manger variants.  If I load them up in the translation management tools only the Label of the page is available for translation, not any of the 'content' of the page.

I can see that I can create a new variant that is selected based on the current language, but this means I need to recreate each of the page layouts.

**What I would like to do is have a single page variant but translate the content of the blocks in them in the same way that I would translate an entity or a custom block.**

I cannot find a way to do this, is this possible?